# Is it possible to disable a <MenuItem> in material-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So I'm trying to write a custom combo box with React and Material-UI. It will show the selected value in the input, provide a list of options (MenuItems) in a dropdown, and have a textbox to enter new options at the bottom.

[Here's what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEEE7.png)

```
<TextField
  className={classes.textBox}
  select
  onChange={handleChange}
  label="My input"
>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <TextField />
  </MenuItem>
</TextField>
```

The problem is whenever I click the TextField, it thinks I'm selecting that  and it closes the dropdown. Is it possible to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Can you share the jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with codepen and can't seem to import the Material-UI components correctly

Answer (score 9):

You can also use AutoComplete, here is the reference in the material ui documentation.
[Material ui autocomplete docs](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#combo-box)

If you wanna disable the MenuItem you can put this into your code.
example:

```
<MenuItem disabled>MenuItem disabled</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The disabled prop does allow me to click the input without it closing the menu, unfortunately it also disables me from entering text. Autocomplete is the next best thing I've found, but I don't actually need to filter or "autocomplete" the options, which compelled me to post this question.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of digging and even more trial and error, I've found a workaround.
In the case of my example, I needed to intercept the click event on my TextField and apply `event.stopPropagation()`.

Full working example:

```
 <TextField
  select
  onChange={handleChange}
  label="My input"
>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem>
    <TextField
      onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
      label="New item"
      onChange={() => { console.log('change') }}
    />
  </MenuItem>
</TextField>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, really tried and couldn't find a way. It looks like it doesn't have the function to control the close event. Like for EX: `Menu` has `onClose` `prop` but `TextField` doesn't have that

Edit:
I think you should use [this](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#playground) the second option `disableClosOnSelect`

Comment: Thanks for checking it out, I finally found a workaround using event.stopPropagation() - check out my answer!